# How may a US President select a successor other than the Vice President?

Tags: united-states, president

Could a US President decide they want to step down and arrange for someone else of their choosing to take their place?

Comment: Constitutionally, they can't. Regardless of changing the VP as mentioned in the answers, ultimately only the VP will succeed the POTUS.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. Although mostly theoretical.

This requires the following steps:

1. Convince the VP to step down voluntarily - the President can't fire the VP -, or remove the VP from office in some other way.
2. Nominate your pick for VP and get it confirmed by Congress.
3. Resign.

However, the actions taken to achieve step 1 are likely to influence the confirmation process in step 2. So I doubt it can be pulled off in practice.

---

There is some historical precedent worth mentioning: **Nixon nominated Ford for VP** after his original VP had to resign. When Nixon himself resigned due to the Watergate scandal eight months later, **Ford succeeded Nixon**.

Note that Nixon hadn't planned to resign at that time yet, so it doesn't exactly match your scenario.

Comment: You may want to mention that the options available for "remove the VP from office in some other way" do not include dismissal, since the president does not in fact have to power to remove the vice president from office.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve that would be to amend the constitution, which requires the cooperation of 2/3 of each house of congress and of 3/4 of the states.

The order of succession is specified by the [25th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution).

In other words, it is so impractical as to be virtually impossible.

Comment: There is one edge case where this is incorrect. If the VP slot is already empty for whatever reason, then the next in line would be the speaker of the house. However that part is not in the 25th amendment. So *puts on tinfoil hat* the president can change the order of succession without an amendment, get rid of the VP, and then elevate whoever he wants.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Wouldn't changing the order of succession require an amendment to the Presidential Succession Act of 1947, which would need to pass Congress?

Comment: @GeoffBall Yes, but passing something in congress is much easier than passing an amendment.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg True, although it seems just as unlikely when it would effectively mean eliminating the Speaker of the House as successor (i.e., it seems unlikely to pass in the House under the current two-party system).

Comment: @GeoffBall See: the tinfoil hat I put on :).

Comment: @DavidGrinberg how would the president get rid of the VP?

Comment: @phoog That was meant to be a joke... the president "gets rid" of the VP... as in some crazy conspiracy you would see in some TV show... Guess I was too subtle.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I wad thinking that it would have to be either political or literal assassination.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I thought that expression was about paranoia. I didn't know it meant something that was far-fetched.

Comment: @David Or just get rid of the VP and appoint his pick for a new one.

Comment: 8 months before Nixon resigned, his VP Agnew resigned. Nixon nominated Ford for VP while Watergate was already developing (although it was still 8 months until Nixon resigned), as per 25th amendment. So it's true that Nixon nominated his actual successor - although he might not have been aware at that time.